# issue with CCScrollLayer in cocos2d-iphone-2.1-beta2

Tags: xcode, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, ccscrolllayer

Hi there I'm having problems as stated with CCScrollLayer in the lateste cocos2d beta, mainly that on compiling I get: `use of undeclared identifier 'CC_GL_BLEND'`. Is there any way to sort this problem that anyone has found yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Safely you can comment that line..anyway blending is already enabled...and everything works fine after this change in cocos2D 2.1 beta.

```
// Set GL Values
#if COCOS2D_VERSION >= 0x00020000
      //  ccGLEnable(CC_GL_BLEND); //Guru
        ccPointSize( 6.0 * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() );
#define DRAW_4B_FUNC ccDrawColor4B

#else
        glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
        GLboolean blendWasEnabled = glIsEnabled( GL_BLEND );
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
```

Comment: Hmmmmm that gets rid of the error, however it doesn't make CCScrollLayer actually work ;) screen dots aren't appearing and can't scroll the layers...

Comment: Yeah you're right.. I was just being stupid and not setting z:2 ;) Out of interest what do the page indicators look like for you? they're square for me, however I've seen them as little glowing dots on tutorials...

Comment: you can remove that page indication dots...showPagesIndicator = NO.

Comment: Yeah I got that :) more interested in having some nice looking dots though ;)